# Creating Tic tac toe in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help me, I want to create a tic tac toe in javascript in div structure, and I want the X is color red and the O is color blue

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We would be happy to help with specific problems if you get stuck, but please show a little bit of effort. If you've already made a start, maybe add the code you've already written.

Comment: I'm so glad about your concern and  I'm so sorry my bad but I really stuck in text color in X and O here me codes please helpme checkin https://jsfiddle.net/ghsxx0n4/

Comment: Just underneath where you set `innerHTML` to either `X` or `O`, you can also set the color: `this.style.color = "red";`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After you set `this.innerHTML` to either `X` or `O`, simply set the box's font color to either red or blue like this: `this.style.color = "red"`.

Take a look at [your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghsxx0n4/1/) at line 63 and 71.